# Unable to debug on remote android emulator with Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, adb, android-debugging

My setup is a Macbook Pro running el Capitan and has the android sdk installed.  I have a Windows 7 Pro installation running as a Parallels 11 guest with Visual Studio 2015 and the Xamarin plugin installed.  Rather than running the android emulator inside the guest os, I run it the Mac host and forward ports 5037 and 5554 in the guest through an ssh tunnel to the host.  The adb client in the Windows guest is able to connect to the adb server on the host.  This setup works great for both Eclipse and Android Studio.  I am able to debug my app on the host emulators from the Windows guest.  When I use VS and Xamarin, it can see the emulators and can even start debugging but as soon as the application starts on the emulator, the app halts and the VS debugger stops.   When I look at the Output window, i see 'Cannot start the debugger.  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: because the host actively refused it.'   I am thinking this has something to do with the remote debugger but I can't figure out why.  Any ideas what may be happening?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I want to do something similar but I want to do it between two PCs on the same network - So that a laptop with less storage doesn't need to Emulator installed taking up valuable HDD space. The emulator isn't really needed when mobile for my use